# GoCardless Node API error in Angular 12 app

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, gocardless

Trying to use the [gocardless-nodejs](https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-nodejs) api module on an Angular 12 app, and followed the instructions.

Importing the module as follows:

```
const gocardless = require('gocardless-nodejs');
const constants = require("gocardless-nodejs/constants");
```

Then trying to create the client:

```
const client = gocardless(
    [gcAccessToken],
    // Change this to constants.Environments.Live when you're ready to go live
    constants.Environments.Sandbox
);
```

but keeps showing this error:
`ERROR TypeError: gocardless is not a function`

Comment: I get the impression that library is not meant to be used in a browser based application, only in a node based application.

Comment: That could be it, but what exactly is stopping me from accessing that function? After all, `console.log` will reveal the results of `constants.Environments.Sandbox`

Comment: If it were a library that was meant for browser based development, then adding the typings for that library would likely eliminate that error. Typescript cannot resolve the function without the typings installed.

Comment: I have added it to the node express app instead, and is working there. Many thanks

Comment: They are developing client api for gocardless. You can checkout in doc. But it's not production ready yet. So only option remaining use inside server side node.js